# Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire component class and a livewire blade component. In the livewire blade component I have a submit button that when is clicked should call the updatedCity method to update the city.

However when the submit button is clicked on the livewire component it appears the error

> Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [ $city ]] in class App\Http\Livewire\WeatherInfo

Thanks

```php
class WeatherInfo extends Component 
{ 
    public $city; 
    private $currentWeatherRes; 
    private $forecastWeatherRes;
    private $unit;
    
    public function mount()
    {
        $this->city = auth()->user()->city ?? '';
        $this->apiKey = config('services.openweather.key');
        $this->getWeatherByCity();
    }
    
    public function test($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;
        $this->apiKey = config('services.openweather.key');
    
        $this->getWeatherByCity();
    }
    
    protected function getWeatherByCity()
    {
    
        $this->currentWeatherResp = Http::get(
            "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?&q={$this->city}&key={$this->apiKey}")->json();
    
        $this->forecastWeatherResp = Http::get(
            "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key={$this->apiKey}&q={$this->city}&days=7")->json();
    
    
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.weather-info', [
            'currentWeatherResp' => $this->currentWeatherResp,
            'forecastWeatherResp' => $this->forecastWeatherResp,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And the blade component like this:

```html
<div>
    @guest
        <h1>Please login/register</h1>
    @else
        <h1>Weather in
            <b>{{ $forecastWeatherResp['city']['name'] }}</b></h1>
    
        <main>
    
            <div>
                <div class="flex items-center justify-between rounded-md">
                    <form wire:submit.prevent="test">
                        <input wire:model.defer="city"
                            type="text" name="city">
                        <div>
                            <x-form.button>Submit</x-form.button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div x-data="{ openedIndex: -1  }">
                <div
                    @click="openedIndex == 0 ? openedIndex = -1 : openedIndex = 0">
    
                    <div>
                        <img
                            src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{{ $forecastWeatherResp['current']['condition']['icon'] }}.png"
                            alt="weather icon">
                        <span>
                    {{ round($forecastWeatherResp['current']['temp_c']) }}º
                </span>
                    </div>
    
                    <div>
                <span>
                    Today
                </span>
                        <span>
                    {{ ucwords($forecastWeatherResp['current']['condition']['text']) }}
                </span>
                    </div>
    
                    <svg style="display: none;"
                         x-show.transition.duration.500ms="openedIndex != 0"
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                         class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                              d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                              clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                    </svg>
                    <svg
                        x-show.transition.duration.500ms="openedIndex == 0"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                              d="M14.707 12.707a1 1 0 01-1.414 0L10 9.414l-3.293 3.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414l4-4a1 1 0 011.414 0l4 4a1 1 0 010 1.414z"
                              clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div
                    x-show="openedIndex == 0"
                    class="w-full border " style="display: none;">
                    <div class="border-t border-gray-200">
                        <dl>
    
                            <div class="bg-white px-4 py-5 sm:grid sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4 sm:px-6">
                                <dt class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">
                                    Feels Like
                                </dt>
                                <dd class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-900 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-2">
                                    {{ round($forecastWeatherResp['current']['temp_c']) }}º
                                </dd>
                            </div>
                            ....
                        </dl>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
    
                @foreach($forecastWeatherResp['forecast']['forecastday'] as $weather)
                    <ul>
                        <li
                            @click="openedIndex == {{ $loop->iteration }} ? openedIndex = -1 : openedIndex = {{$loop->iteration}}"
                            class="w-full">
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{{ $weather['day']['condition']['icon'] }}"
                                         alt="weather icon">
                                </div>
                                ....
    
                            </div>
    
                            <div
                                x-show="openedIndex == {{ $loop->iteration }}">
                                <div>
                                    <dl>
    
                                        <div>
                                            <dt>
                                                Feels Like
                                            </dt>
                                            <dd>
                                                {{ round($weather['day']['avgtemp_c']) }}º
                                            </dd>
                                        </div>
                                        .....
                                    </dl>
                                </div>
    
                            </div>
    
                        </li>
    
                    </ul>
    
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </main>
    
    @endguest
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass anything to your `test()` method, the `$city` argument is already set through `wire:model="city"`

```php
public function test()
{
    $this->apiKey = config('services.openweather.key');

    $this->getWeatherByCity();
}
```

The API key is also not going to change between requests, which means that setting `$this->apiKey = config('services.openweather.key');` in your `test()` method is also redundant, since its set in your `mount()`.

This means that you can actually remove your `test()` method entirely, make `getWeatherByCity()` a public method (instead of a protected one), and then do

```html
<form wire:submit.prevent="getWeatherByCity">
```

Comment: Thanks like that the error dont appears. But when the submit button is clicked in the request is always passed the city of the authenticated user. Do you know what can be the issue? At first it should show based on the city of the authenticated user but if the user types another city in the input and clicks on the submit button it should update according to that new city.

Comment: In the mount there is this:  $this->location = auth()->user()->location ?? ''; because of that.

Comment: The data they enter into `<input wire:model.defer="city" />` will be set to `$this->city` automatically by Livewire, so that's what they will use in the method you call.

Comment: Thanks, yes I already remove that because what I wanted is to only call the method when the user clicks on the submit button, however its not working with <form wire:submit.prevent="getWeatherByCity({{$city}})".

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass `$city` argument to `test` function like so

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="test('the city you want')">
```

Comment: although I don't quite understand what you are trying to accomplish, I think this will fix the error

Comment: Thanks like that the error dont appears. But with <form wire:submit.prevent="getWeatherByCity({{$location}})", for example the user types "Munich" in the input and then clicks on the submit button and it doesnt work, on the console shows : "Uncaught ReferenceError: Dortmund is not defined", Dortmund is the city of the authenticated user.

Comment: @omaresmaeel That doesn't really solve the problem, because with your approach they will have to manually inject the city to that method with JavaScript before submitting the form. Its not even needed at all, because of the `wire:model="city"` input.

Comment: @OsG The error is because you need to quote it, like `wire:submit.prevent="getWeatherByCity('{{$location}}')"` (so that you pass the string of the city, otherwise it will try to use it as a variable, which doesn't exist), but that means it will ALWAYS send the users city in, which sort of defeats the purpose.. You don't need this argument passed, it should be nothing there.